# How does SpaCy make its dependency trees?

Tags: natural-language

I discovered that SpaCy had the ability to make dependency trees. For instance given a question *“To whom did the Virgin Mary allegedly appear in 1858 in Lourdes France?”*

We can create its dependency tree with the following code:

[image: appear is the root of this dependency tree]

I know that it is a set of edges $E$ which represents the relations of labeled dependencies of the particular analysis of $G$. More precisely, an edges $w_i, r, w_j \in E$ represents a relationship of dependence of head $w_i$ towards $w_j$ labeled with the type of relationship. A dependency graph $G$ is therefore a set of dependency relations between tokens in $S$.

For instance we present the dependency graph that follows
 by the following graph:

- $G = (V, E)$
- $V = \{\mbox{It, is, a, replica, of, the, grotto, at, Lourdes, France, where, the, Virgin, Mary}\\ \mbox{reputedly, appeared, to, Saint, Bernadette ...}\}$
- $E=\{\mbox{(is, NSUBJ, It), (is, ATTR, a replica), (a replica, PREP, of),...}\}$

**But I was wondering how does $E$ was made with Spacy? How does the dependency tree method chose which node is the root and which aren't?**

I have heard from [this French paper](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00822996/document) that, on the one hand that $E \subseteq V \times R \times V$ where $R = {r_1, ..., r_m}$ is a finite set of dependency possible names that we call dependency relationship. They can link two tokens in a sentence. A dependency name $r \in R$ is also called a labeled edge. For example, a relationship between a head verb and its subject can be noted with $r = SBJ$.

On the other hand it was an analysis problem of finding the dependency graph that has the highest score for an input sentence.

Yet I haven't seen where there is a child-children ordering creation.

---

The context is that I am using SpaCy dependency trees to get the root of sentences of a paragraph and match it with the root of a question.

For the question given above we have to find the answer in the following paragraph :

> Context — “Architecturally, the school has a Catholic character. Atop
>   the Main Building\’s gold dome is a golden statue of the Virgin Mary.
>   Immediately in front of the Main Building and facing it, is a copper
>   statue of Christ with arms upraised with the legend “Venite Ad Me
>   Omnes”. Next to the Main Building is the Basilica of the Sacred Heart.
>   Immediately behind the basilica is the Grotto, a Marian place of
>   prayer and reflection. It is a replica of the grotto at Lourdes,
>   France where the Virgin Mary reputedly appeared to Saint Bernadette
>   Soubirous in 1858. At the end of the main drive (and in a direct line
>   that connects through 3 statues and the Gold Dome), is a simple,
>   modern stone statue of Mary.”

The expected answer is  *“Saint Bernadette Soubirous”*. 
The sentence having the answer — is *“It is a replica of the grotto at Lourdes, France where the Virgin Mary reputedly appeared to Saint Bernadette Soubirous in 1858”*. Its dependency tree of the sentence containing the answer is :

[image]

I initialy posted this question [on Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/96393/how-does-spacy-make-its-dependency-tree), without success.

Answer (score 1):

Matthew Honnibal, who created Spacy, answered me :

> The full answer is rather complicated :). I've written a few blog
>   posts over the years to make it more accessible. The best place to
>   start is this blog post:
>
> https://explosion.ai/blog/parsing-english-in-python
>
> Since v2, we use a more complicated machine learning strategy,
>   following the general architecture described here:
>   https://explosion.ai/blog/deep-learning-formula-nlp . More specifics
>   about the model architecture can be found in this description of the
>   NER model: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqDHBH9IjRU
>
> The transition system is mostly described by this paper:
>   http://aclweb.org/anthology/D15-1162 , but with some modifications for
>   sentence segmentation.

I already started with the first one which I didn't completly understand yet. I will update this post through my reading progress but leave the question open if a concise question comes to your mind.